# how to export datagrid item into excel file using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, excel, datagrid, export

how to export datagrid item into excel file using Jquery?

Comment: I would collect up the data into an array (object), ajax it to a PHP script that takes that data, converts it to CSV and presents it to download. Would be interesting to see other approaches to this problem.

Comment: function exporttoexcel() {

    $('#export').click(function() {

    
    

    });

} i want to use in asp.net. how to solve this problem?

Comment: I've found this http://skysanders.net/subtext/archive/2010/09/19/json-to-csv.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the code below:

```
function exporttoexcel() {
    $('#export').click(function() {
         window.open('exportdata.aspx');
    });
}
```